# Interpretation of very small GEE Interactions

Tags: spss, interaction, interpretation, generalized-estimating-equations

I have multiple GEE models predicting learning scores from the interactions of psychophysiological data of subjects, e.g. features of Electroencephalograph (EEG), respiration, etc., in a 2 condition design.

Thus for example one model is specified (in SPSS syntax) as follows (covariates are EEG delta power, delta baseline, Respiration rate, and baseline for Resp).

```
* Generalized Estimating Equations. 
* Interaction:norm2_RESP*norm_DELTA. 
GENLIN L_Score_Exp BY COND (ORDER=ASCENDING) WITH norBL_RESP norBL_DELTA norm2_RESP norm_DELTA 
/MODEL COND norBL_RESP norBL_DELTA norm2_RESP norm_DELTA norm2_RESP*norm_DELTA INTERCEPT=YES DISTRIBUTION=NORMAL LINK=IDENTITY 
/CRITERIA SCALE=MLE PCONVERGE=1E-006(ABSOLUTE) SINGULAR=1E-012 ANALYSISTYPE=3(WALD) CILEVEL=95 LIKELIHOOD=FULL 
/REPEATED SUBJECT=SUBJ WITHINSUBJECT=TRIAL*MIN SORT=YES CORRTYPE=AR(1) ADJUSTCORR=YES COVB=ROBUST MAXITERATIONS=100 PCONVERGE=1e-006(ABSOLUTE) UPDATECORR=1 
/MISSING CLASSMISSING=EXCLUDE 
/PRINT CPS DESCRIPTIVES MODELINFO FIT SUMMARY SOLUTION (EXPONENTIATED).
```

The output of this model is an interaction effect which is significant, has B=-.003, and effects for the interaction components, DELTA and RESP, which are significant with B=.003 and B=.008 respectively. Intercept is 10.557

The Bs are very small relative to the intercept, and the B for the interaction has the opposite sign to each of the Bs for components of the interaction alone. 
The question is, based on the model values how does one interpret the interaction*?

Any insights you can lend would be greatly appreciated! :)

*I have interpreted graphically by binning but would like to understand the model itself better.